# How to use Internal Field Separator correctly?

Tags: bash, ifs

I am trying to set the IFS to ':', but it seems to not work. Here is my code,

```
FILE="/etc/passwd"

while IFS=':' read -r line; do
        set $line
        echo $1
done < $FILE
```

When I run my code, it seems to give me the entire line. I have used the set command to assign positional parameters, to extract only the username, but it output the entire line when I try to print the first positional argument `$1`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `while IFS=: read -r user_name _; do printf '%s\n' "$user_name"; done </etc/passwd`

Comment: @Jetchisel Can you explain you answer? I am new to bash programming. And also why can't I use `set`?

Comment: `while IFS=: read -ra gecos_field; do printf '%s\n' "${gecos_field[0]}"; done </etc/passwd`

Comment: @Jetchisel I want to extract other information other than username, like group id and user id. Isn't `set` more appropriate for that?

Comment: `read` builtin in bash has the `a` flag which put the input in an array

Comment: Something like this would've been the best available way to do this back in the 1980s. But it was confusing (as you've discovered), and tended to be buggy even when done "correctly", so most modern shells have added features like arrays that give you better options and more control. Word splitting (i.e referencing variable without double-quotes to split it into "words", as you do in `set $line`) also has a lot of problems, and is best avoided; anytime you see a variable or parameter reference without double-quotes around it, it's a sign that something unwise is being done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `IFS=':' read -r line` reads the complete line
- `IFS=':' read -r name remainder` puts the first field in the variable `name` and the rest of the line in `remainder`
- `IFS=':' read -r name password remainder` puts the first field in the variable `name`, the second field in the variable `password` and the rest of the line in `remainder`.
- etc...

In bash you can use `read -a array_var` for getting an array containing all the fields, and that's probably the easiest solution for your purpose:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=':' read -r -a fields
do
    echo "${fields[0]}"
done < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: You have explained it well, but can you tell me why you have used `{ }`? I am new to bash programming

Comment: @LeuelAsfaw, that is an array , fields is the name of the array and inside of the `[` `]` is the index, counting starts at zero.

Comment: The `-a fields` says read into indexed array `fields`. The `${fields[index]}` is how you access an element of the array. Generically it is `${array[index]}` where if `index=0`, inside `{..}` either `${array[index]}` or `${array[$index]}` are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You're only setting `IFS` for the `read` command. When you expand the `$line` variable, it's set back to the original value. You need to set `IFS` there, not when reading.

```
oldIFS="$IFS" # save IFS
IFS=:

while read -r line; do
    set $line
    echo $1
done < $FILE

IFS="$oldIFS" # restore original IFS
```

Comment: What is oldIFS? and why are you setting it to IFS and resetting it back to IFS? I am new to bash programming.

Comment: I'm saving it so that `IFS` is restored to its original value after the loop iss done.

Comment: Why? I mean I want it to be ':' all the time? Why do I need to set it back to its original value?

Comment: In case you expand variables later in the script and they should use the normal IFS. If you don't need that, you can leave it out.

Comment: Note that this answer contains a [potential pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#OIFS.3D.22.24IFS.22.3B_.2BICY.3B_IFS.3D.22.24OIFS.22), because an empty IFS and an unset IFS have different behaviors and this solution cannot preserve an unset IFS as written.

Comment: @tjm3772 I don't think we need to worry much about that. `IFS` is practically always set. But if it's a concern the workaround in that link can be used.

Comment: Using word-splitting to separate fields won't work well here. For a line like "root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh", the "*" will expand to a list of files in the current working directory.

Comment: Good point. That's why Fravadona's answer is better.